# What's the crash reason?

Tags: ios, autolayout, sigabrt

NSInternalInconsistencyException

SIGABRT

Variable stored in table doesn't match passed in variable 0x282720900.negError{id: 1046} != placeholderForExpressionBeingAdded{id: 1019}

Crashed Thread

```
#0 Thread
NSInternalInconsistencyException
EXC_CRASH
0   CoreFoundation  ___exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib _objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3   Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
4   Foundation  __engineVarForVariable
5   Foundation  __addToEngineVarTableIfNeeded
6   Foundation  -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
7   Foundation  -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
8   Foundation  -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
9   UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
10  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
11  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_addConstraint:]
12  UIKitCore   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints]
13  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateSystemConstraints]
14  UIKitCore   -[UIButton updateConstraints]
15  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:]
16  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:]
17  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:]
18  Foundation  -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
19  UIKitCore   ___100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke
20  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:]
21  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]
22  UIKitCore   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]
23  UIKitCore   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine]
24  xxxxxxxx    -[UIView(category) xxxxxx_layoutSubviews]   UIView+HighLayer.m:29
25  UIKitCore   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
26  QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
27  QuartzCore  __ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE
28  QuartzCore  __ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE
29  QuartzCore  __ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv
30  QuartzCore  __ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv
31  CoreFoundation  ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
32  CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopDoObservers
33  CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopRun
34  CoreFoundation  _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
35  GraphicsServices    _GSEventRunModal
36  UIKitCore   _UIApplicationMain
37  xxxxxxxx    main    main.mm:50
38  libdyld.dylib   _start
```

Comment: This really needs an actual question, not just your stack trace. Please edit your question with relevant code and an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation. The crash reason is calling UIKit methods in subthread. You'd better turn on "Main Thread Checker", although your crash thread is #0.